# Regex to match content of bracket

Tags: java, regex

I want to grab content of bracket in a line. The bracket can be () or [].

I have written this `[\[\(].*[\)\]]` but it matches `(something]` too.
I want to match `(some)` or `[this]` and not `[this)`
Can you guide me?

Comment: This is because you are trying to match this condition: `either [ or ( in beginning` and `either ] or ) in the end`. What you need is a conditional: `if [ in beginning then ] in end or if ( in beginning then ) in the end`. I hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: got it. Thanks @CodeHunter

Comment: Use `"\\[.*?]|\\(.*?\\)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, that the content between either square or round brackets
can include neither "own" brackets nor "other" brackets,
so chars like: `[`, `]`, `(` and `)` are forbidden in the content
to match.

To make the regex more useful, I put 2 capturing groups, #1 between
`[` and `]` and #2 between `(` and `)`, to assist in determining
which brackets are around the content caught.

To match the content between square brackets (with a capturing group) you need:

```
\[([^\[\]()]+)\]
```

and to match the content between round brackets (parenthesses, also with
a capturing group) you need:

```
\(([^\[\]()]+)\)
```

Both above "partial" regexes (for each variant) are alternatives in
the final regex, so they are separated with `|`.

So, the full regex is:

```
\[([^\[\]()]+)\]|\(([^\[\]()]+)\)
```

In case of source text like `[xxxx]`, `xxxx` will be captured as group 1,
whereas in case of `(yyyy)`, `yyyy` will be captured as group 2.

Comment: This answer seems most useful due to use of capturing groups and avoiding 'other' brackets

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is `[(\(.*\))(\[.*\])]`. In that case the regex match the sequence (+whatever+) OR the sequence [+whatever+].

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using single complex regular expression, you may use alternatives i.e:

```
\[.+?\]|\(.+?\)
```

[Regex101 Example](https://regex101.com/r/LkV2fU/1):

**Description:**

- `\[` matches the character `[` literally.
- `.+?` matches any character except for line terminators.
- `+?` quantifier matches between one and unlimited times, as few times as needed.
- `\]` matches the character `]` literally.
- `|` allows alternatives, acts like Boolean OR.
- Regular expression to the right of `|` is similar as described above.

Answer (score 0):

`[?(\[)[\]]|[\)]]+`

might help you if you are sure that your strings are going to be contained inside `(...)` or `[...]`. ]
Your previous expression won't work because you are trying to match this condition: `either [ or ( in beginning and either ] or ) in the end`. What you need is a conditional: `if [ in beginning then ] in end or if ( in beginning then ) in the end` which I stated above.